# Rails is saving empty records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**my routes**

```
TerritoryManagement::Application.routes.draw do

  get "new" => "territories#new", :as => "new"

  root :to => "territories#new"
  resources :territories
  resources :users
end
```

**my model**

```
 class Territory < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
   attr_accessor :name
 end
```

**my controller**

```
class TerritoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @territories = Territory.all
  end

  def show
    @territory = Territory.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @territory = Territory.new
  end

  def create
    @territory = Territory.new(params[:territory])
    if @territory.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Product successfully created!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

**my view**

```
<%= form_for(@territory) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>`
```

**my database**
for some reason the app is generating empty records...

```
sqlite> select * from territories;
1||2011-08-21 09:44:43.611946|2011-08-21 09:44:43.611946
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything immediately that shows what's going wrong. When are these records being generated? When you hit the submit button?

Comment: Yes, when I hit the Submit button

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing attr_accessor with attr_accessible.

EDIT:

[attr_accessor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000478) is a method that creates getter and setter for the given input symbols. Using it in an ActiveRecord models surely is not a good idea if you're rewriting database properties. I can't say off the top of my head what could happen but ActiveRecord surely misbehaves with it. Your name property is a field of your territories table I think and with rails 3 you have to declare which fields you want to be accessibile with mass-assignment. See docs : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

I hope this edit helps ;)

Comment: Oh durr! That *always* gets me. Nice catch!

Comment: @Ryan Bigg It's sooo nice to see you here :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but try to remove the `attr_accessor`, probably you don't need that.

Comment: Spot on, but why is this attr_accessor here a problem? When do I need it?

Comment: Maybe this post can explain it better. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793098/usage-of-attr-accessor-in-rails]