# Rails: set a model attribute as read-only, but allow updating via method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I have an accounts model, where I would like the `balance` to be readonly, but it can be updated via private methods.

Currently

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def deposit(amount)
    # do some stuff and then
    update_balance(amount)
  end

  private

  def update_balance(amount)
    self.balance += amount
  end

end
```

However, this is still possible:

```
account = Account.first
account.balance += 5
account.save
```

I would like for the above to give an error, but still be able to do:

```
account.balance #=> 0
account.deposit(5)
account.balance #=> 5
```

Comment: is there `::balance=` method of Account? where is from? thats because `Account.balance += amount` is expanded to `Account.balance =  Account.balance + amount`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Yes, there is a balance attribute, it's not listed here because in Rails' ActiveRecord, they're already set based on the database schema and aren't required when defining the model.

Comment: Im not seeing such attribute in rails docs, validate your schema / model

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ: here, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793409/3970701

Comment: I think the OP actually meant a database attribute, i.e. `@account.balance += amount` instead of the `Account.balance` class method...

Comment: @BoraMa I did, i'm sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define a private setter for the attribute:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

  def balance=(the_balance)
    write_attribute(:balance, the_balance)
  end
end
```

Then, you are not allowed to call it outside your `Account` class:

```
Account.new(balance: 1234)
# => ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'balance' for 'Account'

Account.new.balance = 1234
# => NoMethodError: private method `balance=' called for <Account ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord` not only the rails gem. This is a common-used [pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) that means mirror-like representation of your DB in your object. So all data-access methods in your models can be defined automatically with ruby metaprogramming mechanisms.

Maybe it's better to keep your logic clear and convenient and write class `AccountManager` that will works on top of `Account` and can provide you such isolation that you need:

```
class AccountManager
  def initialize(account)
    @account = account
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    # do some stuff and then
    update_balance(amount)
  end

  private

  def update_balance(amount)
    @account.balance += amount
  end
end
```

Comment: While this may work, I'm using Ruby, and the convention is to let ActiveRecord handle all the ORM tasks.

Comment: Business logic is not "ORM tasks". And class extraction is widely used in modern development with rails . Btw, beware fat models and hackish class patching.

Comment: Ruby on Rails*.. sorry, I type like a spaz at times. What I needed was to be able to make the `setter` private, which BoraMa answered!