# Railstutorial.org Chapter 6 User.new(name: "name") returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

[image]I am working on Michael Harls turtorial right now. In chapter 6, I am creating new Users in the sandbox console. When I create a new user the picture shows what happens. A new object is returned but the name and the email is nil although I set the attributes as You can see. When I access the attibutes vie user.name it returns the name.Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank You
Sebastian

Model
user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :name, :email
end
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end


end
```

_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Have you generated the User mode like this : "rails generate model User name:string email:string" ?

Comment: Hey, thank You for helping me. Yes, I have. My User model and User controller is exactly like the examples in Michael Hartls book.

Comment: @SebastianPeter if my solution does not help, depending on the rails version you are using, please show us the code and tell us what rails version you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the query performed from your application server, I understand that your problem is connected with the `parameters sanitazion`

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?) [["created_at", "2017-11-18"],["updated_at","2017-11-17"]]
```

In Synthesis, you did not declare your `strong params` in your `users_controller` or your `attr_accessor` in your `user` model.

For `rails` versions until `3`

You need to define an `attr_accessor` in your model `user` class

`user.rb`

```
class User
    attr_accessor :name, :email
end
```

now if you do `User.new(name: 'Fabrizio Bertoglio', email: 'fabrizio.developer@gmail.com')` you should be able to write on those attributes

for more info read this

[usage of attr_accessor in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793098/usage-of-attr-accessor-in-rails#2793409)

If you are using `rails >= 3`

You need to declare `strong_params` in your controller as private method

`users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController
    def create
       @user = User.new(user_params)
       # the rest of the logic
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

`params` is a hash, [`ActionController:Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) is a new Rails class which has special methods. `.require()` only selects the `user` object inside the `params` hash, `permit` makes readable the `name` and `email` fields.

This is the documentation about [strong params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and [in the api](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) you have more info.

### [Sanitize your params](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

Open your console and create your params

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  user: {
    name: "Francesco",
    email:  "francesco@email.com"
  }
})
```

then you `require` the `user` object and `permit` the `name` and `email` attribute

```
permitted = params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
```

Now if you input `permitted` in your console your output should be

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Francesco", "email"=>"francesco@email.com"} permitted: true>
```

the `permitted` field need to be `true`

```
user = User.new(permitted)
```

should work, the reason is what you are doing in the console is:

```
user = User.new()
```

because the `name:` and the `email` you are passing are not `sanitized`, so technically you are passing nothing. That is why you need the `strong_params` in the controller

Comment: I have the exact same model and user_controller  file as Michael HArtl in his tutorial. wehn I write user.name it returns "Michael Hartl" when I write p user name and email are nil. That is the weird thing, at least to me.

Comment: Code is now included. For the Tutorial I use Ruby 5.1.2

Comment: @SebastianPeter what rails version are you using?

Comment: Sorry I meant Rails 5.1.2. Michael Hartl asks to use that Version for the Tutorial.

Comment: @SebastianPeter so why are you not including `strong params` in the controller?

Comment: I did include them and it didn't change anything, soI rolled back to the code provided in the tutorial, which according to the turtorial should work.

Comment: @SebastianPeter just build a class in your `rails console` and try those things out. no need to search here for help. This is the method you are trying to use https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-c-new

Comment: Well thats what I did, but  it doesn't work, it doesn't write the name and email into the user model as it should with the given code. So actually i need help and figure out what is wrong, because otherwise I cannot continue with the tutorial. Thank You anyway for Your effort and Your help.

Comment: @SebastianPeter what about `Sanitizing your Params` in your console. Check out my update in the post.. that is what I mean for strong params.

Comment: @SebastianPeter test the code that I  included in `Sanitizing your params`

Comment: I did everything fine until Useer.new. The same problem. I added a pictur in my original post

Comment: @SebastianPeter I don't like that you are using the `attr_accessor` in rails 5 because, you don't use `attr_accessor` in rails 5. `attr_accessor` will create method like `def name @name end` and `def name=(name) @name = name end` that may override the standard methods that rails 5 has from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

Comment: Yay that was the solution. I deleted the attr_accesor methods.

Comment: Thanks alot, also for explaining the strong parameters to me. I really got it now.

Comment: @SebastianPeter ok. Thanks a lot! sometimes I really don't know if insisting and helping or just suggesting to read the documentation. My advise I read a lot because it will be hard just writing code and getting stuck, if you read your knowledge will expand, so when issues comes out it will be easier to solve them. This documentation is really good http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html